# Resharper multi-line assignment alignment

Tags: resharper, visual-studio-2017

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017 and Resharper Ultimate 2017.1.

When I type multiple line assignments construct like this

```
a =
b =
c = 1;
```

it will auto adjust the code like this:

```
a =
   b =
      c = 1;
```

I search the Resharper and VS options but I didn't find anything useful.

Comment: I prefer above format, but it deforms the code to the bottom one after putting semicolon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For C++ code, you can set "Indentation and Alignment | Continuous line indent" to "None" to get the formatting you prefer, but it will also affect declarations other than assignment.

In general, you can select a piece of code, hit `Alt + Enter` and invoke "Format selection | Configure". This action will open a dialog with formatting settings that affect the selection, so you can play with them and check how formatting changes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didn't know about 'Alt + Enter' trick. I found the settings for C#. It's 'Continuous line indent multiplier'.